# Exception after deleting comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

On the latest version of the SE Android app, I get a NullPointerException after I delete comments (I was cleaning up and deleted 3 in a row), then press the "Tap to view more comments"  link.

The question in case it helps was:
[IntelliJ CSS autocomplete / Emmet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354319/intellij-css-autocomplete-emmet)

Managed to repro again:

- Add 5 or more comments to an answer or question
- Close the app
- open the app again and visit question
- Ensure the "Load more comments"  link is visible
- Delete all visible comments without clicking on the "Load more comments" link
- Tap on load more comments now.

> 03-16 10:14:00.365 E/AndroidRuntime(4586):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.CommentsLayout$3.onClick(CommentsLayout.java:215)

Device : Nexus 5

Comment: Unable to reproduce this on my Nexus 4.

Comment: I know this doesn't help repro but I sent a stack trace through Google Play reporting

Comment: Also it specifically only happens if there are more comments available to load that you haven't read yet

Comment: Managed to repro this. Added more detail and exception message. Additionally, I managed to delete about 4 comments in quick succession. Shouldn't I have to wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.25, coming out sometime soon. Thanks!